# Threads from AsyncTask block UI

Tags: android, user-interface, block, android-asynctask

I have MainActivity which does some Work before it Executes an AsyncTask called "Datensammlung". This task starts some other Threads via different classes. All of Them implement Runnable and work correct. Two are for communication with a Server(TCP Connections) and some are listening for Events/ generating random numbers(Intervall 10 seconds).

Now i want to display some Values every thread works on(i always use synchronized).
When i only start the Listener-Threads, "onProgressUpdate" is called maybe 5 times until it ends updating the UI. When i start the two other threads for Communication nothing is displayed ever.

Why is my UI still blocked although i used asynctasks?

Anyone got an idea? Thank you!

Fabian

AsyncTask:Datensammlung

```
protected Void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {
        int counter = 0;
        ArrayList<String> texte = new ArrayList<String>();
        String test = "";
        for (Input i : this.Dataliste) {

            String text = " "+i.variablenName + ": "+String.valueOf(i.getAbstrakterWert())+"\n";
            texte.add(text);
            test += text;
        //  Log.e("TEXT ", text);
        //  counter ++;
        }

        publishProgress(test);
        Log.e("TEXT", test);
        test = "";
        counter ++;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... listen) {
    TextView t = this.viewList.get(0);
    Log.e("hier isser", "1");
    for (String r : listen) {
        t.setText(r);
        Log.e("hier isser", r);
    }
```

}

One of my Communication Class:

```
package kommunikation;


public class SensorAdapter implements Runnable{
    String iP;
    int port;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ArrayList<Nachricht> nachrichtenliste = new ArrayList<Nachricht>();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    // Konstruktor
    public SensorAdapter(String iP, int port) {
        super();

        this.iP = iP;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public boolean initialisiere_sensor(ArrayList<Textobjekt> pObjekte){
        try {
            socket = new java.net.Socket(iP,port);
            // serialisiere alle Inputs und sende die Daten an das FW
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.writeObject(pObjekte);
            out.flush();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return true; 
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                if (!nachrichtenliste.isEmpty()) {
                    PrintWriter printWriter =new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    Nachricht speicher = nachrichtenliste.get(0);
                    String senden = schreibe_nachricht(speicher);


                        printWriter.print(senden);
                        printWriter.flush();
                        synchronized (nachrichtenliste) {
                            nachrichtenliste.remove(speicher);
                        }

                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    handler.post(this);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }       
    }
```

The Place where the Communication-Thread gets started:

```
public class Kommunikator implements Callback{

    ArrayList<Input> objektliste;
    ArrayList<Textobjekt> textliste;
    boolean update_erforderlich = false;
    public boolean bereit = false;
    private Verbindungsdaten verbindungsdaten;
    private SensorAdapter sadapter;
    private ClientAdapter cadapter;
    Thread sensorfred;
    Thread clientfred;



    // Konstruktor
    public  Kommunikator(ArrayList<Input> plist, ArrayList<Textobjekt> ptextliste){

        boolean check;
        boolean cCheck;
        this.objektliste = plist;
        this.textliste = ptextliste;
        // startet die kommunikation
        this.sadapter = new SensorAdapter("192.168.2.106", 1111);
        this.cadapter = new ClientAdapter("192.168.2.106", 2222,this);
    check = sadapter.initialisiere_sensor(ptextliste);


    if (check ) {
        sensorfred = new Thread(sadapter);
        sensorfred.start();

    }
    // client darf wirklcih erst nach dem sensorlayer starten
    cCheck = cadapter.initialisiere_client(ptextliste);
    if (cCheck) {
        clientfred = new Thread(cadapter);
        clientfred.start();
    }
    this.bereit = true;
    }
    // kann vom Sensor aufgerufen werden um die updates an das framework zu senden
    public void melde(Nachricht na){
            Nachricht speicher =null;
            for (Nachricht n : this.sadapter.nachrichtenliste) {
                if (n.getName().equals(na.getName())) {
                    speicher = n;
                }
            }
            // lösche die alte nachricht
            if (speicher != null) {
                int index = sadapter.nachrichtenliste.indexOf(speicher);
                sadapter.nachrichtenliste.remove(index);
            }
            synchronized (sadapter.nachrichtenliste) {
                this.sadapter.nachrichtenliste.add(na);
            }
    }



    public void melde_Abstract(String name, int Version, float wert){
        // hier synchronized rein???

            for (Input i : objektliste) {
                if (i.variablenName.equals(name)) {
                    // mache Versionscheck und schreibe dann dort den wert
                    synchronized (i) {
                        i.setAbstrakterWert(wert);
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Handler.post() it will execute runnable on UI thread (if handler was created in UI thread). So when you do handler.post(this) you actually do all your communication on UI thread.

Comment: Thank you. But every object holds his own handler.(isn't usefull, right? I just put it in, cause i read it somewhere)

Comment: Much depends where those handler objects were created. Documentation says that runnable will be executed on thread where handler was created. Also it seems that if nachrichtenliste.isEmpty() is true you will keep adding this runnable to execution so it probably will be doing communication multiple times. Not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: hmm... my intention was that i send every "Nachricht" from "nachrichtenliste". When nachrichtenliste isEmpty, the thread has to wait until "Nachrichten" are in the list again. Isn't that what it's doing?

Comment: Lets see. I assume that you created handler in UI thread. Now you entered while(true) loop in some background thread. If nachrichtenliste.isEmpty() is true, you do hndler.post(this) that gets executed on UI thread and enters while(true) loop again. That blocks your UI thread cold regardless of server communication.

Comment: Yes... but like i said, every object creates his own handler.

Comment: Can you post the code where it is created and also the code where those communication objects are created?

Comment: In all cases I am not sure if you want to post runnable with while(true) which will keep reposting itself. That means that at best you will be filling queue with objects that will never complete there run() method.

Comment: I posted everything important from one Communication-Thread and and the class which opens them. ... i just did not finish my work, plan is to replace "true" with boolean i can easily set to false.

Comment: You mentioned that AsyncTask starts communication threads. Consider Kommunikator creates SensorAdapter during initialization and SensorAdapter creates handler during its initialization. So the thread that created Kommunikator is responsible for handler creation.

Comment: OK... PLS STOP THINKING!!!:) you were right, the handler were the problem. although i didn't start them in the main activity, the blocked it. I just deleted all "handler.post" and now it works, THANKS A LOT Alex for your work!! And sorry for not understanding what you meant. Fabian

Comment: Glad that I could help. Good Luck!